# How to properly use ref with a React class component and styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to build a dropdown menu. The base structure `Test` is where I need to detect clicks outside the content area using React `ref` and `styled-components`.

I have checked the related articles in SO but they use hooks not supported on my class component.

Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";

import { theme } from "../theme";

import Icon from "../Icon";

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`};

const SelectorDiv = styled.div`
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
`;

class Test extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  handleClickOutside = event => {
    console.log(this.refs); // undefined
  }


  handleClickInside = () => {
    alert("Clicked inside");
  }

  render = () => {

    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Container disabled={disabled}>
          <SelectorDiv
            onClick={this.handleClickInside}
            ref={"wrapper"}
          >
            <h1>This is the content to click</h1>
          </SelectorDiv>
        </Container>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  };
}
export default Test;
```

The ref is not working property. When clicking outside the are I'm getting `undefined` on `this.refs`. Seens that `styled-components` had issues with this, but it was solved on V4 (I'm using V5.1.0).

How to get the wrapper component inside my `handleOutsideClick`?

Comment: So, I'm not seeing anywhere in this code where you are creating the refs. Where would they be coming from? I have never used refs with a class component, only functional components, but your code certainly does not look like the example in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs

Comment: Have you  created the react.createRef?

Comment: mendes, this is the old way of using ref in React, I think it doesn't work anymore and they don't recommend to use it this way. use `React.createRef()` instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using ref as a string as you tried is a legacy way of React older API. 
And they don't recommended using that:

> If you worked with React before, you might be familiar with an older API where the ref attribute is a string, like "textInput", and the DOM node is accessed as this.refs.textInput. We advise against it because string refs have some issues, are considered legacy, and are likely to be removed in one of the future releases.
>
> Note: If you’re currently using this.refs.textInput to access refs, we
> recommend using either the callback pattern or the createRef API
> instead.

use `React.createRef()` instead,
 And you can access it with `current` attribute of the ref variable like so:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
     super(props);
    
     this.selectorRef = React.createRef(null);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  handleClickOutside = event => {
    console.log(this.selectorRef.current);
  }


  handleClickInside = () => {
    alert("Clicked inside")
  }

  render = () => {

    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Container disabled={disabled}>
          <SelectorDiv
            onClick={this.handleClickInside}
            ref={selectorRef}
          >
            <h1>This is the content to click</h1>
          </SelectorDiv>
        </Container>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  };
}
export default Test;
```

Check it on [sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-monad-kgjr9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

In functional components you can use React hook `useRef()`

[Refs and the Dom](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) 
[useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: Not working yet... constructor is wrong... trying to fix...

Comment: check now, sandbox link included

Comment: Nice job.Thanks.