# Ref current is ready only in class component

Tags: reactjs, react-class-based-component, create-ref

I am using a ref created using createRef to store a string value in a class component. However, whenever I try to change the value of current, I get the error that current is ready only. I am using typescript:

```
class MyClassComponent extends React.Component {
  myRef = React.createRef<string>();

  someFunction = () => {
    this.myRef.current = 'value'; //error here: current is ready only.
  };
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use React.useRef() in class component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499061/how-to-use-react-useref-in-class-component)

Comment: You might also want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65329431/how-to-properly-use-ref-with-a-react-class-component-and-styled-components

Answer (score 0):

*React 18.2.0*, *@types/react 18.2.13*

`React.createRef()` returns the `RefObject` type which the `.current` property is read-only. We can declare the `React.MutableRefObject` type for `myRef`.

> `current`: Initially, it’s set to `null`.

So the final type is `React.MutableRefObject<string | null>`.

```
interface MutableRefObject<T> {
    current: T;
}
```

```
interface RefObject<T> {
    readonly current: T | null;
}
```

```
class MyClassComponent extends React.Component {
  myRef: React.MutableRefObject<string | null> = React.createRef();

  someFunction() {
    this.myRef.current = 'value'; 
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-esaece?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

Also, have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/39062)

Comment: This will give the following error though: `TS2322: Type 'RefObject<string>' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject<string>'.`

Answer (score 0):

`createRef` will give you a RefObject to pass as a `ref` property, the current field of this is readonly.

If you need a mutable reference (commonly used as state that can be changed without triggering a re-render), consider switching to a functional component and use `useRef`.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const myRef = React.useRef<string>()

    const someFunction = () => {
        myRef.current = 'value'; // works, will NOT trigger re-rendering of the component
    }

    return <p> Some Content here... </p>
}
```